# Square-D Homeline vs QO: Which one is better as a subpanel?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I am remodeling my kitchen and therefore need to install 9 AFCI circuits that are compliant with NEC 2020.  I would also like to change wiring in the garage and put 3 circuits there (no need for EV charging yet).

Currently my service is 125 AMP (Eaton BR type panel). In order to relocate many of the existing kitchen circuits and to add new ones, my plan is to install a subpanel inside the house with following specs:

- 200 AMP rated panel with ~40 spaces fed by a 125AMP breaker from the existing panel.

After some research, I have narrowed my choice down to Square-D panels, either the homeline or the QO. The latter is a better quality, but the most frequent criticism I see online is that AFCI breakers for QO are more expensive than homeline.  So I did a quick search and found that the difference in breaker price is just a few dollars.

Which of these two panels is better as a subpanel? Research suggests that with the QO panel, one does not need to remove the bonding jumper between neutral and ground but instead install [a grounding bus as an add-on product](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-23-Terminal-Ground-Bar-Kit-PK23GTACP/100129430). Not sure if this is the case with the homeline panel as well.

Are there any other factors I should be considering when deciding between these two?

Comment: Using the HOM panel might temp you or your heirs to improperly mix the Eaton and Homeline breakers. Personally I have a bit of a grudge with Eaton for improperly building special order panelboards, but I would reluctantly stick with one brand.

Comment: How do you feel about aluminum wire?  "No way in hell ever", "I've heard bad things but could be swayed", or "The past problems were bad technique, sign me up!"

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: none of the above. I feel "Aluminum is the only thing I can afford, unless somehow I was forced to buy Copper".

Comment: @NoSparksPlease: Good point!  I was going to stick with Eaton but those panels are backordered for at least 2 months.

Answer (score 5):

> So I did a quick search and found that the difference in breaker price is just a few dollars.

*Online*?  Online prices are extremely distorted.  In fact, prices in general are extremely distorted [right now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1JlYZQG3lI).  I seriously doubt QO suddenly got cheap; more likely HOM is overpriced right now because of the shortages due to Square D's sourcing blunder.

### There's nothing wrong with any of the six major panels

These are all fine: Eaton CH, BR, Square D QO, HOM, Siemens or GE panels.  Really, each of them has advantages and disadvantages, but only based on *particular things you might be doing*.

For instance, Square D "QO" is certified for DC power (up to 48VDC with random Home Depot breakers, and 120VDC with special-order breakers). *However, QO is obnoxiously overpriced across the board, and as such I avoid them when I don't absolutely need them.*

Eaton CH provides everything you'd hope to get from QO, except DC power support, at competitive prices.

HOM designed to be cheapo, and is the "shoemaker's son" when it comes to product support.  The supply shortages are shameful.  They refuse to make a 60A GFCI for it (why???) On the other hand they do make 150A and 200A breakers for HOM - precious few other makers do - *except they're vaporware because of the shortages*.  /facepalm

Siemens has excellent support for generator interlocks.

Eaton BR has the most versatile selection of specialty breakers, everything from water heater breakers to remote control breakers.  (Eaton CH *would* except some exotica just won't physically fit in the narrower 3/4" package).

GE has a unique approach to double-stuffing that can sometimes be elegant, and *very* unique approach to AFCI on multi-wire branch and 240V circuits.

CH and QO have copper breaker buses, the others have mostly aluminum buses. CH and QO also use 3/4" tall breakers instead of 1", allowing a 40-space panel to fit where a competitor's 30-space would fit.

QO, HOM, GE and Siemens all have a second source for breakers, because Eaton is very price competitive, and has made breakers for their competitors' panels (Eaton CL and CHQ) including a few of their exotics. For QO there is a third source, Siemens.

Nobody makes competitor breakers for Eaton because Eaton doesn't give them any "airspace" on pricing.  That's good for you.

### Features like accessory ground bars are a factor

You **always** remove the bond between neutral and ground -- but this means you need a separate ground bar.  What you're seeing is the question of whether they give you that separate ground bar for free.

Many makers omit the separate ground bar as a cost cutting measure, forcing you to buy it for $7.  That's especially true when the panel is shipped with a main breaker, since they assume you'll be using it as a main panel where the grounds could go on the neutral bar (3 to a lug). Hence many simply multiply the number of allowed circuits by 133.33% and give you that many neutral lugs.

Comment: I need to print this answer and keep a copy handy for reference - thank you.  Two notes:  The homeline breaker is $45.37 and QO is $48.27 at Menards today. Second, what I am most confused about is if you always remove bonding between ground and neutral in the sub panel, why is it necessary to install an additional grounding bar? Is this because when you remove the bond, both sides become neutral? For some reason I have been under the impression that removing bond constitutes disconnecting the two sides - which now seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @cryptic0 That is an unnaturally low price for QO. I would not expect to see it repeated. I am used to seeing $70-90 for xFCI for those.    Key point: Neutral Is Not Ground. They must be kept separate at all places at all times.  There is one exception: ***one*** point in the system where there's an *equipotential bond* to keep neutral from floating at random high voltages. But there can't be two such bonds, or you'll get bad paralleling effects that could start a fire.  You need a ground bar anytime you have multiple grounds to attach to the panel frame.

Comment: I bought a QO plug on neutral panel today and have come to the realization that I cannot remove bonding strap between the two busses. Doing so would disrupt the PON function for half the spaces. Instead, I bought a separate grounding bus which I will bond to the panel and also connect it to the ground wire from the subpanel feed cable.

Comment: @cryptic0 correct, with PON there are neutral bars on both sides, and they cannot be separated. Even if they could, you should never break apart neutral bars, as you will need them for neutrals.   You will need accessory ground bars.  The bolts which attach the ground bars to the chassis will bond it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Homeline is the "price competitive" model from SquareD, QO is the higher quality panel. The difference is probably mostly due to historical reasons given all the consolidations in the electrical manufacturing industry. Product recommendations are off topic, but I'll just say I'd only use QO.

Bonding in a sub-panel has nothing to do with the brand or model. You never bond ground to neutral in a sub-panel. Installing a grounding bus bar is super easy and not expensive at all, if needed (see below).

There is a better alternative anyway. Be sure you get a PON panel (Plug On Neutral) for your GFCI, AFCI, or Dual Function breakers. It really simplifies and cleans up the install. It's fully compatible with normal breakers, but eliminates the need for the curly pig tails from the GFCI/AFCI breakers to the neutral.