# Manually joining SquareD Homeline mini breakers

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I have a circuit for my septic pump that is a 20A 240V taking a “double breaker”/2-pole spot. (A [HOM220](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-20-Amp-2-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-HOM220CP-HOM220CP/202353326))

I’d like to add a mini tandem that keeps that circuit but adds a 50A for a car charger circuit. So a [HOMT220250](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-1-20-Amp-2-Pole-1-50-Amp-2-Pole-Quad-Tandem-Circuit-Breaker-HOMT220250CP/311939378)…I’ve ordered one from a couple places and they are somewhere between 2-10 months backordered (we’ll see, I’ve already been waiting for a few months).

In the meantime, is there a sanctioned thing like a clip that attaches to a [HOMT2020250](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-2-20-Amp-Single-Pole-1-50-Amp-2-Pole-Quad-Tandem-Circuit-Breaker-HOMT2020250CP/202495838) (two independent 20A on the outsides, and a tandem 50A in the middle) to effectively make it into a double tandem?

How bad would it be to just run the readily available HOMT2020250 with individual 20As to the pump while I wait? Perhaps I could 3D print a physical clip and epoxy it, with a plan to throw it out once the real deal arrives?

[image: image of a nearly full Homeline breaker panel with the cover off]
<sup>My nearly full Homeline breaker panel with the cover off</sup>

Green 20A is the spot I’m currently considering, but the yellow 30A I want to do as well, for a brewing subpanel/backup charger in my backyard.

New question [based on this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/228669/90230) is if any other brands are compatible with Homeline panels and if it is okay to use them if they also make mini/combo style breakers? (For instance Eaton BQC looks like I might be able to find a single on eBay/etc.)

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your panel? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Sure, but I’ve been thinking about this for a while and don’t think it’ll be doable based on space available. I also want to do the same with the 30A dryer to add a brewing sub panel…perhaps my follow up question should be if my panel is too full?

Comment: From what you've described, it *is* too full. You are also talking about a lot of big loads - do you have big enough service to handle everything? If your service is large enough, add a subpanel. Maybe replace a double/quad with a big feed (say 60A) to a subpanel and move all the small 15A and 20A circuits. (Note that the subpanel can itself be a main panel in design/name/spaces/price, just keep grounds and neutral separate and it will work just fine. And if you get another Homeline then your breakers can move between the panels.)

Comment: Photo added, not sure why it’s just a link. This is a sub panel served by a 200A breaker in the main panel Smaller, just a few circuits for the upstairs, could maybe add a sub panel downstream of that but wiring would be a bunch trickier. Not sure of my meter/service quantity, at least 200A I suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure what catalog you're looking at, but the [SqD website](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/HOMT220250/quad-tandem-circuit-breaker-homeline-1-x-2-pole-at-20a-1-x-2-pole-at-50a-120-240vac-10ka-air-plug-in-ul/) still lists the HOMT220250 as a stock item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Square D does not seem to like inner/outer tied quadplexes anymore.  They are conspicuous in their absence from the latest catalog.

Simply find a HOMT2020220 quadplex, which is two 20A independents with a 20A in the middle. Replace the 2-pole 20A with that.  Now you have two 20A singles on the outside.  Move two 20A 1-pole circuits to that breaker.

Then do it again with a HOM2020230 quadplex (two 20A circuits with a 30A in the middle).  Now you have definitely freed up 2 spaces and you can fit a common HOM250.

You could also fit your HOM2020250 and put two 20A singles on the outside.

Note that your panel has many red wires on 120V breakers. That is a very bad sign. That usually means the installer was fond of **Multi-Wire Branch Circuits** or MWBCs aka shared neutral.  Make a point ASAP to bone up on those.  Trace all of them so you identify paired hot wires.  Make sure they are landed on circuit breakers that are handle-tied, or 2-pole breakers such as the HOMT2020220.

Noting this is a plug-on neutral panel, it looks like recent work. It is regrettable that a panel with so few available spaces was chosen. I hope the selector enjoyed *the pizza* they bought with the savings.  Noting that it is a subpanel, and can be fully de-energized, I would replace it with a 40-space panel at my earliest convenience.

> In the meantime, is there a sanctioned thing like a clip that attaches to a HOMT2020250 (two independent 20A on the outsides, and a tandem 50A in the middle) to effectively make it into a double tandem?

That's called a "handle-tie".  They must be UL-Listed and would come from the manufacturer. Since it would not provide common trip, as manassehkatz discusses, it could only be used for A/C, water heater and other 240V loads that do not have neutral. Since the 240V load there appears to use neutral, placing it on handle-tied breakers is not appropriate.

> New question based on this answer is if any other brands are compatible with Homeline panels and if it is okay to use them if they also make mini/combo style breakers? (For instance Eaton BQC looks like I might be able to find a single on eBay/etc.)

The bus stabs are slightly different and the wrong breaker will make poor contact and start an arcing fire.  To use a breaker in a panel, either the breaker type must be listed on the panel labeling, or there must be a certification from UL that the breaker is certified in this panel. UL calls this "UL-Classified".  Eaton CL is the only type that is UL-Classified for HOMeline, but the CL line does not include any tandems or quadplexes.

> Any other tips for hooking up EV charging for the first time?

Yeah, that little thing that comes with the car is actually intended as a travel charger. It's meant for opportunity charging "on the road", and so they give you the 2 plugs you're most likely to find "on the road": the standard plug of course, and a Recreational Vehicle (RV) NEMA 14-50 found at every RV park, wealthier friends and some hotels.  *This leads to the misconception that the 14-50 is the standard EV outlet. No, it is the standard RV outlet.*

It's actually best to use a wall unit and hard-wire it. This avoids NEC 2020 requirements for GFCI *on sockets*.  EVSEs already are smart GFCIs.

First you figure out how much electricity your house can spare. This requires a *NEC Article 220 **Load Calculation*** based on the loads currently in the home.  That is compared to the service size, giving the headroom available. Once that is known, you tell the EVSE what that number is, and **it *tells the car* how much current is safe to take**.  Really.  This is how any EV anywhere can use any EVSE anywhere *safely*. (wonder about that?)

The EVSE also contains a "smart GFCI" that will periodically self-reset.  Smart little box.

Some wall-unit EVSEs have DIP switches so you can configure the current.  Others are locked down from the factory so you must buy e.g. a 40A unit.  The "travel" EVSEs have swappable plug dongles; a microchip in the dongle tells the amps of the plug.  Some companies sell 15A, 20A, 30A, and 50A sockets for the travel EVSEs. For Code reasons, the 50A socket assumes a 40A circuit.

This is an advantage to wall-mount and hardwired; they can go 50A, 60A or for some cars as much as 100A.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly helpful answer! I’ll read up on MWBC straight away. I’ve not noticed anything being energized when unexpected but haven’t checked everything. It was probably originally installed in 2006 (during a remodel before we bought the house in 2019), but might have been earlier (not sure history going back further).

Comment: And re:EVSE thanks for the tips, that all makes sense. I got a Wallbox Pulsar Plus 40A (and it is lowerable with DIPs afaik). The load calculation is new and I’ll give it a look, are there any trustworthy online calculators or apps to use or just read it and work it through?

Comment: @owenfi most of the commercial web pages on "load calculations" are dodgy as heck.  However many city inspectors put their load calculation worksheets up on the web.  And they're all about the same.  If they start with 3 VA per square foot of finished space and then pretty much ignore 120V plug-in appliances, you're on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different issues with a "double breaker" vs. "two single breakers":

- Common Shutoff

This means that when a person shuts off one of the breakers, the other is always shut off as well. This can be done using the standard handle attached to a Common Trip double-breaker, but it can also be done using a *handle tie*, which literally ties the two handles together. Handle ties are readily available for most standard single breakers to connect a pair together. They could easily be made for the inner pair of a quad. It would be quite a bit harder to design one for the *outer* pair of a quad - but if you can find one then that would work for common shutoff.

- Common Trip

This is what makes a double breaker more than the sum of its parts. If one hot of the circuit trips, *both* hots are turned off. This is important for safety, particularly with combination 120V/240V devices. If your oven tripped only one of the hots and didn't have common trip then you might think the oven was totally dead - no lights, no control panel, etc. - but find that one of the hots is still live and the oven very dangerous when you start taking it apart to troubleshoot the problem.

Note that even though most breakers are designed to literally flip the handle when they trip, they will trip - cutting off power - even if the handle doesn't flip. As a result, a common shutoff breaker (e.g., handle tied) that is not actually common trip is not guaranteed to turn off the second hot when the first one trips. It *might*, but no guarantee.

If you can find a handle tie *and* your circuit requires common shutoff but not common trip, then you can do that. But I wouldn't count on finding an appropriate handle tie (you can't build your own), and your circuit may *require* common trip anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response! Yeah I think I’ve seen the ties you describe for the middle ones (just a pokey piece of metal with a disc on the middle). I’m guessing but not certain that I need common shutoff and common trip, so that at least rules that path out. Thanks!